# How to search street and housenumber

Tags: postgresql, qgis-plugins

I installed OSM maps on POSTGRESQL database

I installed the osm.pbf file via Osm2pgsql.

after that i created a project in QGIS 3.16 Software.

This installation is for offline use.

I'm unable to perform a street and housenumber search using a plugin called "Discovery"

How do I know if the maps have been loaded correctly?

Is there another way/plugin to search for an address like google map (street and number)?

Comment: You can look (either in QGIS or directly in the DB) at the tables content and see if they look as expected. The next question would be to look at how you have configured the Discovery plugin

Comment: I did not know how the  tables content should be , but I can see that table planet_osm_polygon contain the addr:housenumber but not the streetname 
what is the associatedStreet and how to create this value ?

Comment: it depends how you have configured `osm2pgsql`. In my case, I have loaded all extra attributes in a `tag` hstore column, and I can see `addr:housenumber:`,`addr:street:`, `addr:postcode:`,`addr:city:`. Let's note that this can be different between cities/countries, so you may want to also look at the points or even lines

Comment: Thanks , JGH
can you sent me an example command line to load all tag ?
I want to start from scratch with new DB

Comment: If you are using the "old" pgsql output, just add `--hstore` to the [command](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#use-of-hstore)